# Laravel Restful api Production Server Configuration

Tags: laravel, apache, api, rest, centos

This is my first time moving my **Laravel RESTful** api to the production server in CentOS environment using apache. To make it work I have to use

```
APP_URL=production_ip_address

MARKET_BASE_URI=127.0.0.1:8000
```

and `php artisan serve` or i

> get cURL error 7

Is there any better way to do so if my **APP_URL** and **MARKET_BASE_URI** is same? This works on my local environment with the same URL and no issues, but Connection issues when i use the same in production environment.

Comment: This can be any number of reasons why you are getting the curl error
- your webserver isn’t listening on the loop back address (127.0.0.1)
- there is a firewall your hitting
- the port on production is different 

You question is not that clear on what your problem is, perhaps you can elaborate more?

Comment: Hi Danny! Thanks for replying. My issue is to connect to the API i use MARKET_BASE_URI=127.0.0.1:8000 and not the IP address of my droplet as it gives me cURL error. And if i am using 127.0.0.1:8000 i have to 'php artisan serve' but whenever i SSH out of my server php artisan serve is terminated and it gives me error again. What can i do to fix it?

Comment: You should find the correct up address and port number on where your website is available. The default http port is port 80 or 443 when using https. 

Exiting the SSH session terminates any commands. It should not be required to run a php artisan serve for a production environment at all. So that is definitely not the way to proceed imho.

Comment: Hi Danny, do you think it's fine to run restful api and http service on the same server with same ip address?  or it's better to run them off separate servers?

Comment: That is totally up to you. I’ve been dealing with multiple sites on the same servers perfectly fine. Some with others without proxies to an api. Depends on your needs.

Comment: Sounds good! Thank you for your help and time. I'm going to try running it using droplet ip address with different ip address

Answer (score 0):

use
MARKET_BASE_URI=127.0.0.1:9000

run
php artisan serve --port=9000